# UITableView Prototype cell is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

UITableViewCell is crashing with "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" when i try to modify cell subviews.

Registering tableView cell

```
self.tableView.register(TravelTypeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TravelCell")
```

tablView methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 224
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TravelCell", for: indexPath) as! TravelTypeTableViewCell
    cell.travelTypeSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    return cell

}
```

TableViewcell class

```
class TravelTypeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var travelTypeSegment: UISegmentedControl!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Storyboard images

[image: TableViewCell]

[image]

Comment: You must not register a prototype cell. And is `travelTypeSegment` connected in the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment this

```
self.tableView.register(TravelTypeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TravelCell")
```

As for prototype cells you shouldn't register them as this done automatically for them and make sure `travelTypeSegment` is connected in IB